# How to write Parquet Files to AWS S3 using Apache Beam Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-beam

I am trying to convert Json -> Generic Record -> Parquet --to--> S3. I am able to convert it to Parquet but I don't know how to directly put Parquet file to S3 without storing it into filesystem.

Code I wrote for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MainConfig.class);
    MainConfig options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MainConfig.class);
    Pipeline pipeLine = Pipeline.create(options);
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(options.getAWSAccessKey(), options.getAWSSecretKey());
    options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials));

    Schema jsonSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);
    logger.info(jsonSchema.getFields());
    pipeLine.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput()))
            .apply("Convert Json To General Record", ParDo.of(new JsonToGeneralRecord(jsonSchema)))
            .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, jsonSchema))
            .apply("Generation the parquet files", FileIO.<GenericRecord>write().via(ParquetIO.sink(jsonSchema)).to(options.getOutput()).withNumShards(1).withSuffix(".parquet"));
    pipeLine.run();


}
```

At the end I just want to add that parquet to S3

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? I'm assuming `options.getOutput()` is a path to somewhere in S3, right? S3 is a filesystem, so I'm not quite understanding what you mean by "put Parquet file to S3 without storing it into filesystem."

Comment: yes, and option.getOutput() is s3 filelocation and can i do something like that i want temp storage in normal filesystem and main storage in s3